# error: cannot add a default template argument to the definition of a member of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, default

When I compile the following program using c++11, I get the error `error: cannot add a default template argument to the definition of a member of a class template`. Why doesn't the compiler allow you to have the default template argument in the member function definition?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename A, typename T = int>
class my_class
{
private:
  void dosomething();
};

template<typename A, typename T = int>
void my_class<A, T>::dosomething()
{

}

int main( ) 
{ 
  B<int> obj;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove `= int` when you define the function. You're trying to redefine it, as its written, I believe.

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes. I realize that, but why does the compiler complain about that?

Comment: Because defining defaults in multiple places can be really bad and cause error prone code

Comment: @AdrianCornish Makes sense. Thanks. Is it the same logic as why we don't need a `const` when defining constant member functions?

Answer (score 6):

From [`[temp.param]/9`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.param#9) (bold is me for emphasis)

> A default template-argument is a template-argument (17.3) specified after = in a template-parameter. A default
>   template-argument may be specified for any kind of template-parameter (type, non-type, template) that is not
>   a template parameter pack (17.5.3). A default template-argument may be specified in a template declaration.
>   **A default template-argument shall not be specified in the template-parameter-lists of the definition of a
>   member of a class template that appears outside of the member’s class.** A default template-argument shall
>   not be specified in a friend class template declaration. If a friend function template declaration specifies a
>   default template-argument, that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the
>   function template in the translation unit.

Answer (score 2):

Take the int off the function definition. ie `template<typename A, typename T = int>`
becomes `template<typename A, typename T>`

Comment: This does not answer the question.